# Cut out circle on Google maps

Tags: google-maps

It's easy to draw a circle on a Google map using a Circle object, but is it possible to gray out everything in the world except for a circle, which should remain clear?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is.  But not with a google.maps.Circle, with a google.maps.Polygon that looks like a circle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change map opacity outside circle of Google Maps JavaScript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736418/change-map-opacity-outside-circle-of-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/19746322#19746322)

Comment: This has been answered nicely here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19746322/687677

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547570/google-map-api-v3-color-customization/16541925#16541925) it was something similar to what you're asking for.

The idea is to create two maps, and put one on front of another

Comment: That looks cool, although there will be problems when dragging and zooming he map around. The polygon solution looks like a better bet.