# Circular Google Map using css and html

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am trying to make a circular google map but, the map always appears in square.I am using fixed width css circle(http://codeitdown.com/css-circles/)

```
.circle-text {
width: 500px;
height: 380px;
-moz-border-radius: 50%; 
-webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
border-radius: 50%;
background: #4679BD;
 }

<div id="map-canvas" class="circle-text"></div>
```

With google Maps.

Comment: Could you make a JSfiddle Demo.

Comment: can you add a fiddle too please..

Comment: you can use `-webkit-mask`, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894439/transparent-rounded-corners-on-google-map)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ttcho0sj/3/ .  
i am using this on cordova.Firstly map loads in circle then suddenly it changes its layout to square.

Answer (score 3):

It is working fine

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nfng1sm4/)**

```
<div id="map-canvas" class="circle-text"><div id="googleMap"></div></div>
```

**CSs**

```
.circle-text, #googleMap {
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

Comment: Removed my earlier comment because it seems to work without the outer div too - http://jsfiddle.net/ttcho0sj/3/

Comment: i am using this on cordova.Firstly map loads in circle then suddenly it changes its layout to square.

Comment: In that case will be better if you make a fiddle.

Comment: You can see it is working fine in fiddle.Something with cordova