# How to change Google Map shape?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to make google map like this?[image: Google map trangle shape]
Designer get brilliant idea, and I have to do that...
I never work with google-maps API, but I think its cant be done by API?

Comment: If you can make a [circular map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805915/circular-google-map-using-css-and-html), no reason you can't make a triangular one.

Comment: Here are css for triangle http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/

Comment: @Verma, yes, I know this trick, but it doesnt work for google maps