# How to "cut" elements according to the border-radius of div

Tags: css, html

I have this code for this picture:

**CSS**:

```css
section.content {
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 73%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.79);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 18px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.79);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 18px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.79);
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: #F6F6F6;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<section class="content" id="contentContact">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <form id="contactForm" /></form>
</section>
```

[image: border-radius div]

Then, I Want "cutting" elements according to the border-radius of div and not out of div.
I hope I have explained! Thanks!

Comment: not positive what the question is but usually google maps are rendered as iframes so any thing you want done to the map you'll probably have to do #map iframe as the css selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `border-radius` to `iframe` elements.

Here is an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DNXkW/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS for the outer or parent div that has the rounded corners.

```
overflow:hidden
```

For the google map it's not as easy.

Have a look at a few different options:

http://maps.forum.nu/temp/gm_rounded_corners.html

[Is there any trick to put rounded corners on a Google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579330/is-there-any-trick-to-put-rounded-corners-on-a-google-map)

[Transparent rounded corners on Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894439/transparent-rounded-corners-on-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

Make css for all inner elements (child elements):

```
opacity:0.99;
```

or any opacity < 1.