# CSS3 rounded corner with google map

Tags: google-maps, css

I am trying to apply rounded border using with css3 border-radius property in Google map but its not work in chrome, in other browser its work great. 
Any ideas or suggestions? Here i am putting my code and waiting positive reply.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Google Maps Testing</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css" >
#map {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 120px; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom:0; 
    z-index: 1; 
    overflow: hidden;
    border:solid 3px #00FF33; 
    border-radius:15px; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 200px; 
    margin:0 auto;  
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-mask-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
}
#wrapper {
        position:absolute; 
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="map" ></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var i,marker;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: 'marker_icon.png',
        borderRadius: 20,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]+' <img src="map-pin.png" /> <div style="background:#090;height:100px;width:200px;">yeah its working perfect ..!!!</div><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><form><a href="javascript: alert(\'foo!\');">Click Me</a></form>');
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As much as we want to, we currently can't.

The alternative is overlaying rounded corner cut-outs over each of the corners, to make it look like the corners are rounded. Basically create a rounded square, invert it so it becomes a cut-out shape, split into 4 corner pieces, position each corner inside a parent container.

Example

```
.container { width: 400px; height: 300px; position: relative; }
.map { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.corner { width: 30px; height: 30px; position: absolute; background-image: url(my/corners.png) }
.corner.topleft { top: 0; left: 0; background-position: 0 0; }
.corner.topright, etc.
```

Answer (score 31):

I currently had the same problem with Safari and Chrome. I had to put translate3d to zero for Chrome and add a webkit-mask-image for Safari:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```

Comment: It works! nice hack. Is it only needed for Chrome and Safari?

Comment: I just used the safari portion of this to fix an issue with my map ignoring the border radius of a parent div (a couple of levels up by adding the mask to the parent. Thank-you so much, I was out of ideas

Answer (score 21):

You have to style the div within the map element, not the map element.

```
map > div {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I had to style both that div and its immediate child div

Comment: Instead of setting it to the immediate child's div like @guss-hogg-blake said, i added `overflow: hidden;` to the above css.

Comment: overflow: hidden; worked for me as per @Terrabythia's comment.

Comment: Perfect answer. Clean and no hacks. This even fixed the damn flickering problem when zooming. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me as I added the z-index property:

```
#map {
    ...
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to achieve the same effect without the use of any image, here is a solution on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alxscms/3Kv99/. You can also add a faded inner border if you'd like, without breaking the navigation inside the map.

[image: Google maps with rounded corners and border]

Here is the code for the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
    <i class="top"></i>
    <i class="right"></i>
    <i class="bottom"></i>
    <i class="left"></i>
    <i class="top left"></i>
    <i class="top right"></i>
    <i class="bottom left"></i>
    <i class="bottom right"></i>
</div>
```

And the style (scss):

```
$radius: 10px;
$thickness: 5px;
$border-color: rgba(black, 0.15);
$background-color: white;

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px;

  & > i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    &.top {
      top: 0;
      border-top: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        top: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-top: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }
    &.right {
      right: 0;
      border-right: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        right: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-right: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }
    &.bottom {
      bottom: 0;
      border-bottom: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        bottom: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-bottom: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }
    &.left {
      left: 0;
      border-left: $thickness solid $border-color;
      &:after {
        left: -$radius/2 - $thickness;
        border-left: $radius/2 solid $background-color;
      }
    }

    &.top:not(.right):not(.left),
    &.bottom:not(.right):not(.left) {
      height: $thickness;
      left: $radius+$thickness;
      right: $radius+$thickness;
    }

    &.left:not(.top):not(.bottom),
    &.right:not(.top):not(.bottom) {
      width: $thickness;
      top: $radius+$thickness;
      bottom: $radius+$thickness;
    }

    &.top.right,
    &.top.left,
    &.bottom.right,
    &.bottom.left {
      width: $radius;
      height: $radius;

      &:after {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        width: 1.5*$radius;
        height: 1.5*$radius;
      }
    }

    &.top.right {
      border-top-right-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-top-right-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
    &.top.left {
      border-top-left-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-top-left-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
    &.bottom.right {
      border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
    &.bottom.left {
      border-bottom-left-radius: $radius;
      &:after { border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5*$radius; }
    }
  }
}

#map {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  .gmnoprint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What I found useful was to wrap the `agm map` around a `div` and change the `div` CSS to provide that rounded corner.

```css
.map {
  height: 391px;
  width: 784px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="map">
    <agm-map [zoom]="15" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
      <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, all I needed was the `overflow: hidden` that was the magic trick. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented this idea in a project I was working on. Here is an example of how I made it work...

Live preview: http://jsfiddle.net/h6Tkq/

HTML...

```
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
```

With the following CSS...

```
#map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It appears to be working in the current version (56.0.2924.87) of Chrome.

Comment: It didn't went I wrote that comment 7 months ago.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to find out an alternative solution as Google Map v3 is not supporting the usage of border-radius property which you are trying to use.

Answer (score -1):

This was proposed in another answer, but it missed `z-index:1` in the CSS so even in the JSFiddle it didn't work.

HTML is:

```
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6Tkq/112/)

Answer (score -1):

If you use bootstrap 4, you can add class rounded. Worked for me with v3 maps.

Answer (score -1):

**2023**: In modern browsers, simply add border-radius to the map div:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border-radius: 10px;"></div>
```